# How to "group" data in a column in a dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, numpy, dataframe

I have a dataframe, these are the first lines:

```
(idx1) AMAZONAS 15
(idx2) AMAZONAS 2
(idx3) ANTIOQUIA    881
(idx4) ANTIOQUIA    696
(idx5) ANTIOQUIA    632
(idx6) ANTIOQUIA    702
```

as you can see, there are some names that repeat, and I need to group all that names that are repeated and sum the values on the right. 
i've tried functions pd.apply, groupby, but it didn't work Idk why. Please help!!!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the dataframe **df** has columns like **name** and **count**, for, respectively, values *AMAZONAS* and *15*, for example, you cand do:

```py
df.groupby('name')['count'].sum()
```